# Overriding JavaScript/HTML/CSS/ etc... files in projects

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, infrastructure

I'm trying to build a web library that is supposed to be an infrastructure to my other projects.
In those other projects I'll be overriding some of the scripts, styles and other components, but some of the functionality should stay the same and not be overriden.
I'd like NOT to copy all the files to every project, but packing them and extracting the files in production will be ok.

What is the best/standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [Mozzila Web Developer Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/HTML_and_CSS)
or may overriding a style rule in CSS:

```css
a {
color: white;
color: red !important;
display: none;
display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/HTML_and_CSS'>Mozzila Test</a>
```

btw if you want to override Files:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="overrided.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way you work with other frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation. The order in which you load your `css` files into `html` lets the latter overwrite the former, if there are rules of same or higher specificity.

So just create your base styles and then load overrides:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="overrides.css">
```

Comment: I meant that I'm looking for a way to give the developer all the files he needs, but in the same time to hide them from him (until deployment) unless he wants to override them.  I want it to be very easy for him to use my library so he doesn't need to see what he doesn't want to change.

Comment: Yeah, give him your base.css full of stuff and an empty overrides.css that he can fill as he needs. It's pretty simple my friend. There's not really any way to "hide" css.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```css
.button{
  padding : 12px 6px !important;
  color : #434343 !important;
  margin : 1em 3em !important;
  }
```

It works everywhre via !important that browser only must use these properties in all same name classes . If you use this with other css framework , you need to put tour CustomCss under bootstrap css's.

***ANOTHER SOLUTION***

USE SASS OR LESS

Comment: he shouldn't have to use !important all over the place, a simple order of loaded css files or their specificity is enough. !important is too hacky

Comment: I understand , but there are situation  which can not help YOUR mentioned method . For example in bootstrap without !important YOU could not remove focused blue  border color. Another situation you do not want that bootstrap some element changes color when hover:, focus: or similiar things .  Shortly  give to your element id or class , and use with properties !important .